# How to configure different paths to the same 'controller' and 'templateUrl'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I'm new to AngularJs and I'm following some tutorials to learn something about.

Now I'm dealing with **routes**. My config is something similar:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/',
    {
        controller: 'Controller1',
        templateUrl: 'View1.html'
    })
    .when('/one',
    {
        controller: 'Controller1',
        templateUrl: 'View1.html'
    })
    .when('/two',
    {
        controller: 'Controller2',
        templateUrl: 'View2.html'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
```

Now I'm wondering, is it possible to merge the first two `.when` to a single condition?
I tried somethig like: `.when(['/', '/one'], ...` but it doesn't work.

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
.when('/one',
{
    redirectTo: '/';
})
```

Or in this case, leave out the when('/one') because the wanted behavior is the same as otherwise().

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use arrays of routes as an argument for 'when'. More info here:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider

So short answer, no, I do not see how you could do that.